# OxyPlot WPF - Get slected column

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I am trying to get selected (clicked) column in OxyPlot WPF. Is there any way to do that? My WPF code so far:

```
    <oxy:Plot x:Name="plotDiagram" Title="Output" >
        <oxy:Plot.Axes>
            <oxy:CategoryAxis ItemsSource="{Binding Item.barDisplayData1}" LabelField="DisplayText"/>
            <oxy:LinearAxis MinimumPadding="0" AbsoluteMinimum="0"/>
        </oxy:Plot.Axes>
        <oxy:Plot.Series>
            <oxy:ColumnSeries Title="{Binding Item.Title1}" FillColor="Green" IsStacked="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Item.barDisplayData1}" ValueField="Value" />
            <oxy:ColumnSeries Title="{Binding Item.Title2}" FillColor="Red" IsStacked="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Item.barDisplayData2}" ValueField="Value"/>
            <oxy:ColumnSeries Title="{Binding Item.Title3}" FillColor="Yellow" IsStacked="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Item.barDisplayData3}" ValueField="Value"/>
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
    </oxy:Plot>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no selected column property. You need to implement the mousedown event on the column series and determine which column was clicked using the GetNearestPoint() function.

```
void columns_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)  
{         
    var cols = sender as ColumnSeries;    
     OxyMouseDownEventArgs args = ConverterExtensions.ToMouseDownEventArgs(e, sender);
    if (cols != null)      
    {         
         TrackerHitResult nearestPoint = cols.GetNearestPoint(args.Position, false);           
         if(nearestPoint != null) {
            object selectedColumn = nearestPoint.Item;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with event params - ColumnSeries_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e). MoseButtonEventArgs != OxyMouseDownEventArgs

Comment: OxyPlot Versions:   <package id="OxyPlot.Core" version="1.0.0-unstable1974" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="OxyPlot.Wpf" version="1.0.0-unstable1974" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: In that case, you could try to use ConverterExtensions.ToMouseDownEventArgs(this MouseButtonEventArgs e, IInputElement relativeTo). This will convert MouseButtonEventArgs to OxyMouseDownEventArgs

Comment: I managed to get mouse args but there is no GetNearestPoint method on OxyPlot.Wpf.ColumnSeries object  :(